# Ferrite cable core selection best practices for USB 2.0 Full Speed

Tags: rf, usb, emc, signal-integrity, ferrite

From signal integrity and best possible EMI suppression perspective should ferrite cable core match the characteristic *differential* impedance of 90ohms @ 12MHz (for USB 2.0 Full Speed) in order to eliminate transmission line impedance mismatch?

Comment: Are you referring to a ferrite cable clamp or something that is used on each data line? Maybe link the data sheet?

Comment: I'd like to use something like Laird's 28R1127-000 (https://www.laird.com/sites/default/files/28r1127-000-datasheet.pdf) as "on board" EMI filter for all USB lines (D+,D-,5v,GND) which is close to 90ohms @ 12 Mhz from datasheet. But I'm interested to know in general the science behind it.

Comment: almnk, That's the equivalent of a ferrite cable clamp (in that it wholly surrounds both data lines) and therefore it falls in the category addressed in my answer. The science behind it is how transformers work so maybe if you have some understanding in that area try researching common mode chokes as a further step to understanding.

Comment: Andy, thank you, your response makes me rethink my question. 90ohms is differential impedance from specification and that 220ohms @ 100Mhz from datasheet is for common mode.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a brand new question to avoid invalidating my answer. Changing the goal-posts once an answer has been given is not something folk regard as polite. Having said that I see you have modified your question and, thankfully, it doesn't invalidate my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *should ferrite cable core match the characteristic impedance of 90ohms*

If you are referring to one of these (a ferrite cable clamp) then, the answer is **no**: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ferrite-sleeves/1512789).

The reason the answer is **no** is because these types of clamp deal with common-mode noise and largely unaffect the integrity of the balanced and differential USD data signal hence, the clamp's loss impedance is irrelevant to the characteristic impedance of the cable.